# rust: lifetime issue, need a hand

Tags: rust, type-systems, lifetime

I am making an analog of c++'s iostream for rust recently, but get confused by the lifetime system.
I want to store a reference of reader or a bare reader in the `IStream`, so I store an `Q` in the structure. And than I use an phantom type `D` for converting `Q` to `R`.

Here's the explaination:

- `R` is the `Reader` where I actually need.
- `Q` is the store type of `R`, so `Q` maybe a bare `R` or reference `&mut R`.
- I use `D` to convert `Q` to `R`.  Because `borrow_from_mut(&mut R)` gives me an `&mut R`, and `borrow_from_mut(R)` also gives me an `&mut R`. Thus it could be `D: BorrowFromMut<Q>`.
- and `D` can be converted to `R` by derefrence. So `&mut D: DerefMut<R>`
- because `&mut D` can be dereferenced to `D`, but I need the `&mut D` dereferenced to `R`, here must use a `trait object` to dynamic dispatch the `deref_mut` method, because of the absence of `UFCS`.(trick: `let tmp: &'c mut Q = &mut *self.istream.borrow_mut();`)

Such trick makes `IStream` able to store both `&mut R` and `R`.

But the code can't compile because of a lifetime issue:

```
let tmp: &'c mut Q = &mut *self.istream.borrow_mut();
//the Q borrowed from the RefCell only valid in the block, doesn't out live 'c.
```

how can I solve it?

here is the code sample:

```
pub struct IStream<'a,'b,R:'a+'b,Q:'a+'b,Sized? D:'b> where R: Reader, D: BorrowFromMut<Q>, &'b mut D: DerefMut<R> {
    istream: Rc<RefCell<Q>>
}

impl<'a,'b,R,Q,D> Clone for IStream<'a,'b,R,Q,D> where R: Reader, D: BorrowFromMut<Q>, &'b mut D: DerefMut<R> {
    fn clone(&self) -> IStream<'a,'b,R,Q,D> {
        IStream {
            istream: self.istream.clone()
        }
    }
}

impl<'a,'b,'c,F,R,Q,D> Shr<&'b mut F,IStream<'a,'c,R,Q,D>> for IStream<'a,'c,R,Q,D> where R: Reader, F: FromStr + Default, D: BorrowFromMut<Q>, &'c mut D: DerefMut<R> {
    fn shr(mut self, output: &mut F) -> IStream<'a,'c,R,Q,D> {
        let tmp: &'c mut Q = &mut *self.istream.borrow_mut();
        let mut reader: &mut D = BorrowFromMut::borrow_from_mut(tmp);
        let mut real_reader: &DerefMut<R> = &reader;

        let mut buf = String::new(); // a string buffer

        loop {
            if let Ok(byte) = (*real_reader.deref_mut()).read_byte() {
                if byte == '\u{A}' as u8 || byte == '\u{20}' as u8 {
                    break
                } else {
                    buf.push(byte as char);
                }
            } else {
                break
            }
        }

        *output = FromStr::from_str(buf[]).unwrap_or_default();
        IStream {
            istream: self.istream.clone()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could make your example both [smaller and compilable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can  paste it into the [playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/) and run it to see your error, then it's a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to outsmart yourself. You don't need to be able to store a reader or a mutable reference to a reader at the same time, because you [can easily convert](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.ByRefReader.html) such mutable reference to a full-fledged reader. Without these complications your code will look like this (note the example of `by_ref()` below):

```
#![feature(slicing_syntax)]

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::default::Default;
use std::io::ByRefReader;

pub struct IStream<R> where R: Reader {
    istream: Rc<RefCell<R>>
}

impl<R> Clone for IStream<R> where R: Reader {
    fn clone(&self) -> IStream<R> {
        IStream {
            istream: self.istream.clone()
        }
    }
}

impl<'b, F, R> Shr<&'b mut F, IStream<R>> for IStream<R> where R: Reader, F: FromStr + Default {
    fn shr(self, output: &'b mut F) -> IStream<R> {  // '
        let mut real_reader = self.istream.borrow_mut();

        let mut buf = String::new(); // a string buffer
        loop {
            if let Ok(byte) = real_reader.read_byte() {
                if byte == '\u{A}' as u8 || byte == '\u{20}' as u8 {
                    break
                } else {
                    buf.push(byte as char);
                }
            } else {
                break
            }
        }

        *output = FromStr::from_str(buf[]).unwrap_or_default();

        self.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let stdin_ref: &mut _ = &mut stdin;  // a mutable reference to a reader

    let is = IStream { istream: Rc::new(RefCell::new(stdin_ref.by_ref())) };

    let mut x: uint = 0;
    let mut y: uint = 0;

    is >> &mut x >> &mut y;

    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproduction of the error you mentioned:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn foo<'a>(rc: &'a RefCell<u8>) { 
    let b: &'a u8 = &*rc.borrow();
}

fn main() {
}
```

This fails to compile with

> borrowed value does not live long enough

By definition, the result of `borrow()` has a scope that is tied to the scope it's called in, you can't "trick" it by specifying a different lifetime. All that does is make the compiler tell you you can't do that.